# kernel build: why does 'make install' complain about missing modules?

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, kernel-modules

I'm building a 3.2.x kernel on a RedHat Enterpise system.

During 'make install' it takes a very long time and is complaining:

> ERROR: modinfo: could not find module xxx

I assume its probing existing modules but why?  I created a small test module that I loaded by hand with insmod and sure enough it shows up as

> ERROR: modinfo: could not find module testmodule.

Could someone explain to me what's going on here?  Why does 'make install' care about existing modules that may (or may not) be loaded?

Comment: I suggest a `make clean` before building.